# single word to describe a story based on real-life and later extrapolated

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a good single word to describe a story that is based on real-life events and people, and extrapolates them to build a hypothetical future scenario?

Comment: If there were a better single term than based on, I think the film and tv industries would be using it.  But what does your research reveal?

Comment: I came across the term [`faction`](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/types-of-story-or-play), a story, film, or television programme that is a mixture of real and imaginary events or people

However, `faction` is also used to mean `a small organized dissenting group within a larger one`, and I'm extrapolating future events, not inventing facts, so it seems to be only partially correct

Comment: Why not just use the term _extrapolation_? For example, instead of _based on real events_, you could say _extrapolated from real events_.

Comment: Ummm, this is just called *fiction*. All fiction is just an extrapolation of real life and built upon to build a new story.

Comment: I think the best you can hope for is a phrase.

Answer (score -1):

ScienceFaction ...we invented the word for you over morning tea.